# How to get different tabs in all view in view based app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to implement the tab bar in a view based application.Now what i want is each view contains different tabs based on that view .How would i add the tab bar in all views.

Comment: May you make yourself clear, because i can't really get what you want.

Comment: I have 4-5 views which have different tab bar than all other views. so how to show different tab bar for only those 4-5 views

Comment: Even though you will use only one tab bar controller in AppDelegate, you can programatically change items in tab bar. Depending on view, you can change items in tab bar. Also in tabBar:didSelectItem: delegate of tab bar, you can handle actions according to item selected on different-different screens.

Comment: can you give any sample code link??

Comment: Please illustrate little more

Comment: check my answer may be it will helpful for you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370748/overlay-tabbar-with-a-view/12370879#12370879 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316331/removing-tabbar-controller-when-uibar-button-clicked/12316415#12316415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502071/creating-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically) and its answers you will find examples on how to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

Purva, you can achieve this by using the following tact:-

When-ever your tab click, the control should go to the required delegate as pointed-out by Rahul.Now, at that place you, need to get the array of your view-controllers from tabController and replace them with the new array of viewControllers which you want to become tab.

In any concern, give a shout over me.